# numberposts, showposts, posts_per_page. What's the difference?

Tags: wordpress

Every time I see different answer.

Can anyone give me a good reliable answer on the difference between
`numberposts`, `showposts`, `posts_per_page` when querying posts?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

They are all the same and does exactly the same thing. Usage are slightly different though

- `numberposts`, `posts_per_page` and `showposts` are all valid in [`get_posts()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_posts/). `numberposts` is set to `posts_per_page` before being passed to `WP_Query`. Check the source code

  ```
  if ( ! empty($r['numberposts']) && empty($r['posts_per_page']) )
      $r['posts_per_page'] = $r['numberposts'];
  ```
- `posts_per_page` and `showposts` are all valid in `WP_Query` but `numberposts` not. If `showposts` is used, it is set to `posts_per_page` in the `WP_Query` class. See the source code

  ```
  if ( isset($q['showposts']) && $q['showposts'] ) {
      $q['showposts'] = (int) $q['showposts'];
      $q['posts_per_page'] = $q['showposts'];
  }
  ```

Although the codex says `showposts` is depreciated, there is still no depreciation notice in core.It was however replaced in favor of `posts_per_page`.

To answer your question, `posts_per_page` is probably the best to use as `numberposts` and `showposts` are being set to `posts_per_page` in the `WP_Query` class