# Why set 'numberposts' to -1?

Tags: php, wordpress

When creating a custom wordpress query, why would someone set their 'numberposts' to -1? What is the outcome? I've googled a bunch and can't seem to find this (probably) very simple answer!

```
ex: $args = array( 'numberposts' => -1);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edited 3/31/2020 to correct inaccuracies (see original answer below)**

To set the number of posts to be retrieved by the get_posts() function.

If the $args array in the original question were to be passed to the get_posts() function, it would retrieve all of the published posts in the database.  So if you called this function in the template file of a site with 736 published posts, it would report Posts in Get Posts: 736

```
function get_all_posts(){
    $posts = get_posts(array('numberposts' => -1));
    echo '<h1>Posts in Get Posts: ' . count($posts) . '</h1>';
}
```

numberposts does not have an effect when used as an argument to WP_Query.

**Note:** in contrast to what commenter Toskan wrote below, it is not necessary to pass 'posts_per_page'=> -1 in order to achieve the result above.  In my tests the function above and the function that follows did the same thing regardless of the total number of posts in the DB.

```
 function get_all_posts(){
    $posts = get_posts(array('numberposts' => -1, 'posts_per_page' => -1 ));
    echo '<h1>Posts in Get Posts: ' . count($posts) . '</h1>';
}
```

However, they are correct that if you set 'posts_per_page' to a positive value, it will override whatever value you pass in the 'numberposts' argument.  It is also possible that if 'posts_per_page' is set in a filter and you set 'suppress_filters' to false, it might override the value of 'numberposts' regardless.

**Previous (incomplete and inaccurate, but accepted) answer:**

**Simple Answer:**

To return all of the results of the query.

**Longer Answer:**

The purpose is to set the WordPress pagination system to display all the posts that are available in the query.  If you change `numberposts` to a positive integer it will display only number of posts per page.

For example, if your query would ordinarily return 150 results, setting `numberposts` to 15 would give you the first 15 results.  Setting it to 150 would give you all the results.  However, if the number of results increased it would continue giving 150 results.  So `-1` is used to essentially hard code getting all the results.

In PHP `-1` is a common way of expressing "give me everything."

> Note: 'numberposts' and 'posts_per_page' can be used interchangeably.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts

I prefer to use `posts_per_page` because it expresses the intent more clearly.

Comment: Thank you @vlasits for this thorough answer and explanation!

Comment: I wish I could downvote this harder. It needs more downvotes. numberposts -1 in wp_query will max return 10 if posts_per_page isnt set to -1

Comment: Thanks, @Toskan for alerting me to the misleading aspect of my original answer.

Comment: @vlasits could be that if you use WP_Query its different. Shouldnt be, right? maybe is the problem, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34840187/533426

Comment: @Toskan Correct.  Your original comment sent me into the code.  In the code for WP_Query if you pass numberposts to WP_Query it is ignored.   I think the idea is that WP_Query uses pagination by default, so using posts_per_page as the default for determining the number of posts returned makes sense even if you turn off pagination with 'no_paging'.  But get_posts() turns off pagination by default, so setting the posts returned with 'posts_per_page' seems weird.  But under the hood, get_posts just turns of pagination, assigns 'numberposts' to 'posts_per_page' and passes it to WP_Query.